# Freeform pro duplicate fields on the fly

Tags: solspace-freeform

do you know if its possible to create freeformpro fields:

Name (text) | Age (select) | Diet (text)

but somehow on the front end allow users to duplicate these on the fly, eg

"Please submit the names etc you wish to order for" the user then clicks to add a name (and above fields) and then another… so you may be able to add up to 10 names and then submit (a kind of booking form for a person to add attendees to his/her order)? At the moment, I have created form fields for each of the above  10 times (Name1, Age1, Diet1 and Name2, Age2, Diet2  and Name3, Age3, Diet3
 etc x10) and the fields are displayed ready to be filled in ie max of ten able to be booked. So for example if the user needs to order just 3 names (with Age and Diet fields) they would fill in x3 of these out of the 10 available and leave the rest empty… fine with that but if there is a better way without too much jQuery etc that would be great! Alternatively would it work if in the HTML I just resued Name1, Age1, Diet1 x10 times (within x10 divs)? Thanks